# Is it possible to disable the auto format by copy&past in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, copy-paste, developer-tools

When I copy&past my source files IntelliJ autoformat the file content. E.g. change the order of imports.

How can I disable this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this behaviour under `Settings/Preferences (on macOS) | Editor | General | Smart Keys | Reformat on paste`

Answer (score 0):

In "Setting" --> "Editor" --> "CodeStyle"-->"Java" you find a tab imports. There you can change this behavior